Django celery media folder backup issue
I create a library to get backup to Google Drive using with Google Drive api in python. Actually its work well but when I use with celery my library, celery do not wait for compress my media folder(I guess). Its every time get backup zipped and encrypted backup to Google Drive but its empty. If I go to my django app container and I write my custom command to get media backup, its work well. I have been dealing with 2 week. Is someone can help me about celery or my library.
Tried:

asycn compress process.

my library -> https://github.com/ylrmali/py-googledrive (README.md is not updated)
# gcapi/dbhandler/management/commands/pymedia_backup.py

import asyncio
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandParser
from django.conf import settings
from gcapi.cryption import Cryption
from gcapi.drive import GCDrive
from gcapi.compress import compress_folder
import os 
import tarfile
import datetime

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Restore database"

    def add_arguments(self, parser: CommandParser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--encrypt',
            action='store_true',
            help='Encrypt media folder'
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--compress',
            action='store_true',
            help="Compress media folder"
        )   
        
    def __success_output(self, text):
        """
        Success output
        """
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(str(text)))
    
    def __error_output(self, text):
        """
        Success output
        """
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR(str(text)))
    
    def __remove_temp(self, temp_list: list):
        """
        Remove temprary used files
        """
        for file in temp_list:
            os.remove(file)
            
    async def _create_media_tar_async(self, media_folder: str):
        """
        Asynchronously create the tar file for the media folder.
        """
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self._create_media_tar, media_folder)

    def _create_media_tar(self, media_folder: str):
        # Create a timestamp for the media folder
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f")
        tarname = f'media_{timestamp}.tar.gz'
        
        try:
            # Create a tar file
            with tarfile.open(tarname, 'w:gz') as tar:
                # Walk through the media folder and add each file to the tar archive
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(media_folder):
                    for file in files:
                        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                        # Add the file to the tar archive with the relative path
                        tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, media_folder))
            return True, tarname
        except Exception as exc:
            return False, exc

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        _drive = GCDrive() 
        _cryption = Cryption()
        media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        is_encrypt = options['encrypt']
        is_compress = options['compress']
        temp_files = []

        # Call the asynchronous function within the synchronous context
        c_status, c_output = asyncio.run(self._create_media_tar_async(media_folder=media_root))

        if c_status:
            temp_files.append(c_output)
            media_root = c_output
        else:
            self.__remove_temp(temp_files)
            return self.__error_output(f"Fail: Compress error!: {c_output}")

        if is_encrypt:
            # encrypt media.zip folder
            status, encrypted_file = _cryption.encrypt_file(file=media_root)

            if not status:
                self.__error_output("Fail: Encryption error!. Check credentials.json !")
            temp_files.append(encrypted_file)
            media_root = encrypted_file

        # send to drive

        try:
            response = _drive.upload(file=media_root)
            if response:
                self.__success_output(
                    f"Success: Media backup successfully upload to Google Drive\n Message: {response}")
            self.__remove_temp(temp_files)

        except Exception as e:
            self.__error_output(f"Media backup failed: {e}")

# tasks.py

@shared_task
def db_backup():
    try:
        call_command('pybackup', '--encrypt')
        logger.info("Database backup completed successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error occurred during database backup: {e}")

@shared_task
def media_backup():
    try:
        call_command('pymedia_backup', '--encrypt', '--compress') # no more need --compress flag
        logger.info("Media backup completed successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error occurred during media backup: {e}") 

# Define periodic tasks
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'db_backup': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.db_backup',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/3'), # every three hours
    },
    'media_backup': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.media_backup',
        'schedule': crontab(),
    },
}

I want to get media backup as compressed and encrypted. But celery does not wait for finish compress process.
